# Get ID from url string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, url

What is the safest way to get an ID from an URL, which looks like this:

```
http://www.website.abc.net/fixed/27386323
```

So I would try to split the string and take the last part:

```
var parts = url.split("/");
var id = parts[parts.length - 1];
```

It would also work, if the user types:

```
www.website.abc.net/fixed/27386323
```

But it wouldn't work, if the URL would be (last slash)

```
http://www.website.abc.net/fixed/27386323/
```

So would a regex be better? Or should I use JQuery?

Comment: Just check if the last element is empty, and use the 2nd-to-last element instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use a regex for `.match`:

```
([^\/]+)\/?$
```

and grab captured group #1. `/?$` makes trailing slash optional in this regex.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dG0cQ1/3)

Comment: Would it be possible to check also for the correct domain and 'fixed'-parameter? So this `www.another-website.net/fixed/27386323` would give me an error... And: The result has to be a number, not any other string..

Comment: Sure you can use this regex `www\.website\.abc\.net\/fixed\/.*\b(\d+)\/?$`. Let me know if this works then I can update the answer

Answer (score 1):

You may remove any trailing slash at the end of the url and then use the same approach which you are currently doing. This way it would work in both scenarios ( with or without slash ).

```
var url = 'http://www.website.abc.net/fixed/27386323/';
var url2 = url.replace(/\/$/, ""); // remove any trailing slash at the end
alert(url2.split('/')[url2.split("/").length -1]); // gives the desired id
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/879moj9m/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can simply trim any trailing slash like this:

```
if(url.substr(-1) === "/") {
    url = url.substr(0, str.length - 1);
}
```

and then check for the id.

```
var parts = url.split("/");
var id = parts[parts.length - 1];
```